# Why Is Javascript Passing Element, Not ID?

Tags: javascript, html, parameters, onclick

I want to use a javascript function to define a dropdown type element that I will be using several times during page creation. My definition code is like this:

```
function getSingleColorDropdown(use_id, initial_text) {

    let list_id = "dropdownList_" + use_id;
    let text_id = "dropdownText_" + use_id;
    let menu_id = "dropdownMenu_" + use_id;

    html = "<div class='dropdown dropdown_inline'>\
                <button id='" + list_id + "' data-toggle='dropdown' \
                        class='btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown_text_wrapper' \
                        type='button' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>\
                        \
                        <span id='" + text_id + "' class='dropdown_text'>" + initial_text + "</span>\
                        \
                </button>\
                \
                <div id='" + menu_id + "' class='dropdown-menu' \
                     aria-labelledby='" + list_id + "'>\
                     \
                     <button class='dropdown-item' type='button' value='red' \
                                    onclick='storeSingleColorDropdown(" + text_id + ", this.value)'>\
                            red\
                     </button>\
                     \
                     <button class='dropdown-item' type='button' value='yellow' \
                                    onclick='storeSingleColorDropdown(" + text_id + ", this.value)'>\
                            yellow\
                     </button>\
                     \
                </div>\
            \
            </div>"
            
    return html
}

function storeSingleColorDropdown(use_id, result) {
    console.log(use_id)
    console.log(use_id.id)
    console.log(result)
    document.getElementById(use_id).innerHTML = result;
}
```

It works perfectly, except when I pass `text_id` to `onclick`, instead of passing the id (which should be `"dropdownText_" + use_id`), it passes the entire line `<span id='" + text_id + "' class='dropdown_text'>" + initial_text + "</span>`. I can't figure out why this is so. I've tried different ways of passing `text_id`, but this is the only way that "works" in that it passes something instead of breaking.

How can I get it to pass `text_id` appropriately in `onclick`?

Comment: The problem is simple, in JavaScript, element's id can be used to get the whole element. So JavaScript though you're passing the whole element to the function as parameter.

Comment: oh, that's interesting. How would I tell it to just pass the id then?

Comment: Use backtick to strigify the id e.g `\`${text_id}\``

Comment: Hm, when I try `onclick='selectDropdown(\`jQuery{text_id}\`, this.value)'` it literally passes `jQuery{text_id}` instead of evaluating it. And if I try it outside the quotes (like so: `onclick='selectDropdown(" + \`jQuery{text_id}\` + ", this.value)'`, it breaks.

Comment: You must put dollar sign after backtick e.g  `onclick = 'selectDropdown(\`${text_id}\` )'`

Comment: Isn't the $ equivalent to jQuery? Wherever I've seen the code, whether I use $ or jQuery it depends on how it's initialized. In my case, everything is with jQuery.

Comment: You should use jQuery noconflict...

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this as a simple example

```
storeSingleColorDropdown(" + text_id + ", this.value)
```

It'll become:

```
storeSingleColorDropdown(dropdownText_something, this.value)
```

But you want:

```
storeSingleColorDropdown('dropdownText_something', this.value)
```

Thus, you could fix this by doing:

```
storeSingleColorDropdown('" + text_id + "', this.value)
```

---

I have not tested the above, but I think it might be correct. Anyway, do you have time to talk about our lord and saviour [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't like the single quote in single quote (the overall string) and escaping didn't work. I see your point though